# Access a instance method from other model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model in my application. Now I want to replace some  user model coding into 2 categories likely employ.rb and customer.rb under a module users, to avoid more number of codes in a single model. I want to access a method send_mail in customer.rb after a user created.

user.rb

```
after_create:send_msg_on_order

def send_msg_on_order
Users::Customer.send_mail
end
```

users/customer.rb

```
  def send_mail
  Mailer.send_mail_to_customer.deliver
  end
```

And I am getting undefined method `send_mail' for Users::Customer:Module error.

Comment: How much in common do those models have? Are you using sti?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `send_mail` method as instance method but calling it as a class method. Either make it a class method or create an instance of `Customer` model and call it.

Making the method a class method:

```
def self.send_mail
  Mailer.send_mail_to_customer.deliver
end
```

If you wish to keep it an instance method, then call it like this:

```
after_create:send_msg_on_order

def send_msg_on_order
  Users::Customer.new.send_mail
end
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can also call like this

```
def send_msg_on_order
   Customer.send_mail
end
```